# Pulling data from an API

Tags: json, python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio, subscription

I've been stuck on this issue for a while and would appreciate any help. I am trying to pull the price of bitcoin and ethereum from an API, using 2 subscriptions. At the same time I am also sending the websocket an authorization message to logon to my account.

The problem I am having is the subscription code does not filter out the last_price as I am expecting.

If I remove the logon/authorisation message than it filters the output fine (though I need to authorise for other uses), and it only gives an output once rather than a continuous stream of prices like a subscription should.

My code is:

```
import asyncio
import json

import websocket


btc = None
eth = None

async def call_api2(msg1, msg2, msg4):
    async with websockets.connect('wss://testapp.deribit.com/ws/api/v2') as websocket:
        await websocket.send(msg1)
        btc_ticker = await websocket.recv()
        btc_ticker_load = json.loads(btc_ticker)
        #print(btc_ticker_load)
        btc_ticker = await websocket.recv()
        btc_ticker_load = json.loads(btc_ticker)
        global btc
        btc = btc_ticker_load["params"]["data"]["last_price"]
        print(btc)


        await websocket.send(msg4)
        eth_ticker = await websocket.recv()
        eth_ticker_load = json.loads(eth_ticker)
        #print(eth_ticker_load)
        eth_ticker = await websocket.recv()
        eth_ticker_load = json.loads(eth_ticker)
        global eth
        eth = eth_ticker_load["params"]["data"]["last_price"]
        print(eth, 'this is eth')
        print(btc-eth, 'this is the delta')

        await websocket.send(msg2)
        while websocket.open:
            authenticate = await websocket.recv()
            # do something with the notifications...
            authenticate_load = json.loads(authenticate)
            print(authenticate_load)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
  asyncio.ensure_future(call_api2( json.dumps(msg1), json.dumps(msg2), json.dumps(msg4) ))   
  loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  pass
finally:
  print('closing loop')
  loop.close()
```

My output does not filter the btc and eth prices only, instead the whole output comes like so:

```
{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'method': 'subscription', 'params': {'channel': 'ticker.ETH-PERPETUAL.raw', 'data': {'timestamp': 1575898571330, 'stats': {'volume': 47214.31236, 'low': 148.5, 'high': 151.9}, 'state': 'open', 'settlement_price': 148.89, 'open_interest': 165337623, 'min_price': 147.26, 'max_price': 153.27, 'mark_price': 150.26, 'last_price': 150.25, 'instrument_name': 'ETH-PERPETUAL', 'index_price': 150.29, 'funding_8h': 0.0, 'current_funding': 0.0, 'best_bid_price': 150.25, 'best_bid_amount': 39114.0, 'best_ask_price': 150.3, 'best_ask_amount': 9398.0}}}
```

Comment: Have you tried single quotes `'`?

Comment: @OrestisZekai I haver tried that, unfortunately it makes no difference either way.

Comment: Can you provide the content of your msg1?

Comment: Thanks guys but I managed to figure it out.

Before the subscription streams the data it sends an intial confirmation message to say that the subscription is succesful. 

This message does not have ["params"]["data"]["last_price"], so I solved it by using a Try, Except function.

Comment: Rather than use a try/except you could use `.get` on the dictionary. That won't fail in that case and you can give it a default value rather than it be None.

Comment: @PirateNinjas Thanks for the pointers, I will look into it... in terms of speed does it make a difference?

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference on the speed